# How to dynamically redirect in Vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a requirement for location-specific re-routing. The website structure is like the following:

home (redirects to activityType with city passed)

```
/ (root) 
|
|__:activityType
       |
       |____:city
              |
              |_______ /
              |
              | _______ /:itemName
```

basically, `www.home.com` should point to `www.home.com/:activityType/:city`
and on that page user can click on the item to be further passed to `www.home.com/:activityType/:city/:itemName`

Now I am not sure how to structure vue-router properly, since anything except hardcoded values gives me back 404 err.

```
return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    fallback: false,
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
    routes: [
      { path: '/', redirect: to => {
        const { params } = to
        if (!!params.activityType){
          params.activityType = 'music'
        } 
        if (!!params.city) {
          params.city = 'new-york'
        }
        return '/:activityType/:city'
      }},
      { path: '/:activityType', children: [
        { path: ''}, // similar redirect like from root
        { path: '/:city', name: 'venue-page', component: homepage, children: [
          { path: '/:item', component: venue}
        ]}
      ]},
    ]
})
```

Any idea how I can get the desired behavior with homeroute, and putting basically my homeroute as a fallback?

Comment: What is exactly your problem ?

Comment: @Jérôme I have a function to get location by ip. by default I when user comes to mysite.com I want it to point to mysite.com/activity/location, where activity is either gotten from localStorage, or if there isn't any I get the default value. If user tries to delete /location from browser, I still want mysite.com/activity to forward to mysite.com/activity/location.

Comment: You can manually redirect the user directly inside your component used when going on mysite.com using ‘router.push({path: ‘somepath’})’ or ‘router.go()’.

Comment: I am aware of that, but is there a sleek way to do it from within router component similar to what I have written in example above?